# Nginx proxy pass based on http method

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to filter `OPTIONS` calls from a `location` and redirect them somewhere else? Tried this configuration but didn't work:

```
  location /example/ {
    proxy_pass http://example.com;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass_request_headers  on;

    limit_except OPTIONS {
      proxy_pass http://anotherurl.com;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways this can be achieved. The easiest one, in my opinion, is with the [map](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) directive:

```
upstream some_backend {
    server example.com;
}

upstream another_backend {
    server anotherurl.com;
}

map $request_method $upstream {
    default some_backend;
    OPTIONS another_backend;
}

server {
    ...
    location /example/ {
        ...
        proxy_pass http://$upstream;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Using [upstreams](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#upstream) is not mandatory but recommended. In most cases it will make your configuration easier to read, maintain and extend. Nevertheless, if you prefer to omit the `upstream` blocks and write your hosts directly in the `map` block, the configuration will still work:

```
map $request_method $upstream {
    default example.com;
    OPTIONS anotherurl.com;
}
```