# Nginx upstreams for POSTs and GETs

Tags: nginx, configuration

Is it possible for nginx to handle post and gets with different upstreams?

Let's say I've got an url 'http://example.com/task'. The 'task' uses GET and POST method. Can I configure nginx to proxy_pass GETs to upstreamA and POSTs to upstreamB?

Thank you for your reply :)

Comment: You could, but it would involve the use of `if` within a location block. If you're okay with that, then I could provide a sample config.

Comment: Uh, if is evil. I'd rather think about changing urls ;) Thank you for fast reply.

Comment: Lol, if is indeed evil. Good luck!

Comment: This is the second time that this question is being asked today. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40649846/nginx-proxy-pass-based-on-http-method